# Trouble with the space in pop up menu of Gnome 3.14 shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and have trouble with Gnome shell theme. I want to fix it myself but it's still a mess. I think it's about ".popup-separator-menu-item" in Gnome Panel Pop-up menu, I can't make the space shorter as I want by using "padding". Please help and sorry for my bad English.

Here's the code (of Zukitre theme):

```
.popup-separator-menu-item {
    -gradient-height: 1px;
    -gradient-start: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -gradient-end: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -margin-horizontal: 0em;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
```

Image: https://flic.kr/p/rUjnuq

Comment: The problem may be that you are using a out-of-date version of the theme for 3.12. You should currently be able to get a version of the Zukitre for Gnome 3.14 from [here](http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukitre-490751685) (or [here](https://github.com/lassekongo83/zuki-themes), use the download zip button). If you have found a bug with the theme you can report it [here](https://github.com/lassekongo83/zuki-themes/issues) - note that if you are using the version of the theme from a Ubuntu repo you should try the theme from its original source first to see if it is also affected

Comment: Are there any other possible fields? I think that's for the space between the menu bar and pop-up.

Comment: @Wilf Yeah, I'm using the theme for Gnome 3.14, I downloaded from the same link. Zukitre theme is just an instance, I mean most of themes have too big space like this.
Default theme (https://flic.kr/p/s9Dqku) and Ceti 3.14 theme (https://flic.kr/p/rUnagG)

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm sorry I don't understand your question but I think it's the space of the separator, it's too big and I want it smaller.

Comment: How much smaller (if you edit a screenshot of what you want it to look like that would help). reducing the padding to `padding: 0;` *does* reduce the gap, but by such a small amount it makes no difference

Comment: @Wilf I tried, padding: 0; makes no affect.

Comment: I think that that field you're trying to edit has to do with the spacing between the GNOME menu bar and the pop-up, not the spacing between the items in the pop-up. Are there any other places in what you're trying to edit that might have to with the menu items?

Comment: Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 is still a development version, so you should file a bug...

Comment: It does, but as I said 'by such a small amount it makes no difference' .The issue likely involves the margin and/or padding of other element affecting it, or another styling rule overriding this one.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to make your own theme without having to manually recode a existing one, [this theme](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Elegance-Colors-305966388) may work for you.

Comment: Maybe there's another place which I don't know.